# Как улучшить страничку соглашения об использвании персональных данных?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Помогите пожалуйста улучшить страничку соглашения об использвании персональных данных.

Я сделал небольшой сайт, который состоит из нескольких страниц, заполненных текстом. Задумка такая, что пока пользователь не потавит галочку на страничке соглашения, то не будет иметь доступа к другим страничкам.

Здесь сайт: https://zlodiak.github.io/ng2/feedback/1

Здесь исходники: https://github.com/zlodiak/ng_feedback

Проблема в том, что я создал сервис, в котором содержатся глобальные переменные(в частности булевая переменная, которая содержит информацию о том, подтвердил пользователь соглашение или нет) и подключаю его на каждой страничке, которая требует проверки. То есть на всех страничках. Пока их мало, но по мере роста сайта их будет очень много.

Это проблема. Нужно более элегантное решение.

Мой сервис глобальных переменных выглядит так:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Response, Headers, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalVarsService {

    private isAgreeOk = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor() { };

  getAgreeState(): Observable<boolean> {
    //console.log('this.isAgreeOk', this.isAgreeOk);
    return this.isAgreeOk;
  };  

  setAgreeState(state): void {
    //console.log('set isAgreeOk', state);
    this.isAgreeOk.next(state);    
  };   
}
```

Вот компонент одной из страничек:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { GlobalVarsService } from '../services/global-vars.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question.component.scss']
})
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private globalVarsService: GlobalVarsService,
                        private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkAgreeState();
  }

  private checkAgreeState() {
        this.globalVarsService.getAgreeState().subscribe(state => setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('subscribe', state);
          if(!state) {
                this.router.navigate(['/agree']);
          }
        })); 
  };

}
```

Видно, что код функции checkAgreeState(), импорт GlobalVarsService, импорт роутера, инициализация globalVarsService, инициализация роутера нужно повторять на каждой страничке сайта. Это тупиковый путь.

Я пробовал перенести функционал проверки в app-component.ts , в хук ngAfterViewChecked. Но этот способ хоть и работал, но вешал браузер. Кстати хук ngAfterViewChecked даже если содержит только console.log() всё равно вешает браузер, непонятно зачем он вообще существует в ангуляре.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь Route guards https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'agreement' },
    { path: 'agreement', component: AgreementComponent },

    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'agreement' }
];
```

#### AuthGuard

```
import { GlobalVarsService } from '../_services';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private _router: Router, private _gvs: GlobalVarsService) { }

    canActivate() {
        if (this._gvs.getAgreeState()) {
            return true;
        }

        this._router.navigate(['/agreement']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это гениально. Спасибо. Правда, я не понял зачем после перенаправления return false ставить, но это не существенно. Главное что проблема решена

Comment: `return false;` нужен потому что `canActivate` должен вернуть true либо false в зависимости от того можно ли активировать данный route, хотя вполне возможно undefined тоже сойдет.